# id & name error when using an EditorTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

It took about 3 hours for me to be sure why the following (explained) error happening; and finally I'm sure that it's an mvc error. I would like to ask your opinions.

I've created an editor template and put it under the ~/Shared/EditorTemplates folder. And I carefully used the file name to be equal with type name (because I don't want to use the second parameter with "@Html.EditorFor" helper method). As a result editor template was working fine : Except the postbacks; I definately couldn't get values from model because the model was always null. I tried to change the id & names of inputs and selects carefully and did the post back: it's working fine.

So; the problem is: when I use the editorTemplate it gives "Question.[0].QuestionContext" as a name and "Question__0_QuestionContext" as an id for inputs and selects; however I was expecting "Question[0].QuestionContext" as a name and "Question_0__QuestionContext" as an id.

Then I realized that I was using @foreach inside the EditorTemplate. Then I switch back to @for but nothing changed. You can find the template below:

```
@using DenemeMvc3Application3.Helpers;
@model DenemeMvc3Application3.Controllers.LocalizedNameViewModels

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => modelItem.ElementAtOrDefault(0).LanguageDropDownList)</td>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => modelItem.ElementAtOrDefault(0).Value)</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @for (int index = 0; index < Model.Count; index++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem[index])
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So I changed my template to easier one by declaring the foreach loop outside of the editortemplate & inside of the view and using the editor template only for singular item. And it worked. So I made a small investigation on how templating works on mvc3 by using reflector; and I found the bug I suppose:

The problem is caused by System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo class's public string GetFullHtmlFieldName(string partialFieldName) method which is used by System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions class's private static MvcHtmlString SelectInternal(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string optionLabel, string name, IEnumerable selectList, bool allowMultiple, IDictionary htmlAttributes) method.
So as a result whenever we use @Html.DropDownListFor(/*blah blah*/) inside a foreach or a for loop in an EditorTemplate we get the error.

I also want to show you the bug-code below to clarify:

```
    // TemplateInfo method
public string GetFullHtmlFieldName(string partialFieldName)
{
    /*Here's the extra dot: causing the error.*/
    return (this.HtmlFieldPrefix + "." + (partialFieldName ?? string.Empty)).Trim(new char[] { '.' });
}

// SelectExtensions method
private static MvcHtmlString SelectInternal(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string optionLabel, string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, bool allowMultiple, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    /* blah blah */
    string fullHtmlFieldName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
    /* blah blah */
}

// SelectExtensions method -> @Html.DropDownListFor
private static MvcHtmlString DropDownListHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, string optionLabel, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    return htmlHelper.SelectInternal(optionLabel, expression, selectList, false, htmlAttributes);
```

So, what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then I realized that I was using @foreach inside the EditorTemplate.
>   Then I switch back to @for but nothing changed.

How about getting rid of all loops and simply:

```
@model IEnumerable<FooViewModel>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => modelItem.ElementAtOrDefault(0).LanguageDropDownList)</td>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => modelItem.ElementAtOrDefault(0).Value)</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.EditorForModel()
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Much better? No loops and correct names and ids. It's ASP.NET MVC that will automatically render the editor template for each element of your model collection.

and the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/FooViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model FooViewModel
<tr>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeProperty)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeOtherProperty)</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have more complicated rendering problem, results in the same:

instead of getting

```
xxxx.yyy.zzz.MyCollection[%index%]
```

one gets:

```
xxxx.yyy.zzz.MyCollection.[%index%]
```

I think the original MVC method:

```
public string GetFullHtmlFieldName(string partialFieldName)
{
    /*Here's the extra dot: causing the error.*/
    return (this.HtmlFieldPrefix + "." + (partialFieldName ?? string.Empty)).Trim(new char[] { '.' });
}
```

is not perfect, because partialFieldName parameter's value can be e.g. "[0].AAA"

There is already an issue on this at ASP.NET MVC CodePlex:

[GetFullHtmlFieldName really should take indexers into account](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/5495)

"FIX" on this can be:

```
public static IHtmlString EnsureCorrectCollectionName(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string partialName, IHtmlString somethingToBeRendered)
{
            //TODO: check http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/5495 to remove this fix

            if (partialName.StartsWith("["))
            {
                string fullHtmlFieldName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(partialName);

                if (fullHtmlFieldName.EndsWith("." + partialName))
                {
                    string htmlCode = somethingToBeRendered.ToHtmlString();

                    string nameAttribute = "name=\"" + fullHtmlFieldName + "\"";
                    var p = htmlCode.IndexOf(nameAttribute);

                    int endIndex = p + nameAttribute.Length - partialName.Length - 2;
                    var correctedHtmlCodeStart = htmlCode.Substring(0, endIndex);
                    var correctedHtmlCodeEnd = htmlCode.Substring(endIndex+1);

                    return new HtmlString(correctedHtmlCodeStart + correctedHtmlCodeEnd);
                }
            }

            return somethingToBeRendered;
}
```

---

Darin Dimitrov suggested using

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

but how then can one generate inside a model editor code right hidden input "xxx.yyy.zzz.MyCollection.Index" with value="%index%"

```
@model FooViewModel
<tr>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeProperty)</td>@*rendered as name="xxx.yyy.zzz.MyCollection[%index%].SomeProperty"*@
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeOtherProperty)@*rendered as name="xxx.yyy.zzz.MyCollection[%index%].SomeOtherProperty"*@
        <input type="hidden" name="xxx.yyy.zzz.MyCollection.Index" value="@(%index%)"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

?